# MSAL Angular HTTP interceptor for localhost not attaching token

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, msal-angular, angular-token

I'm trying to call a localhost API and to attach the bearer token on the header. It should be done by `msal-angular` automatically.
For now, I have added the localhost API route to the `protectedResourceMap` but there is no bearer token inside the header. Tried to add jsonplaceholder and `graph.microsoft` to make an HTTP post call to it and it works. The only issue is when I try to make an HTTP call to localhost API.

I'm using:

```
@azure/msal-browser@2.12.0
@azure/msal-angular@2.0.0-beta.0
```

I have used factory providers for the interceptors in the `app.module.ts`.

```
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
   protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', [
     'user.read',
   ]);

  protectedResourceMap.set('http://localhost:5000/api/add', [
    'api://custom api consent'
  ]);

   protectedResourceMap.set('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/', [
     'api://custom api consent'
   ]);

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap,
  };
}
```

It is also registered in the `app.module.ts`:

```
    providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: MsalInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
        {
          provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
          useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,
        },
        {
          provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
          useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory,
        },
        {
          provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
          useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory,
        },
        MsalService,
        MsalGuard,
        Msal,
        BroadcastService,
  ],
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're having trouble with a similar issue, I found a solution that may help. It turns out that using the **protectedResourceMap** function more dynamically and providing a relative URL works better. The problem was caused by using the full route, including the domain name and port number, such as "http://localhost:4200/api/add".
The solution was simply to add "/api/" to the protectedResourceMap like this:

```
protectedResourceMap.set('/api/', [
'api://custom api consent'
]);
```

Comment: What is `custom api consent`? Can you share an example?

Comment: It is ability to provide scope for the user, example  new Map([ 
          ['Enter_the_Graph_Endpoint_Here/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
      ]). Please read this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code

Comment: If user can see the token from the request header, is it safe?

Comment: Thanks for this, I was struggling with this for a couple of days and this answer helped me.

Answer (score 2):

We were struggling with @Bozhinvski's answer above; specifically what `api://custom api consent` meant.

This value needs to be aligned with the Application ID URI, which by convention is in the format of `api://<Application (client) ID>` where the Application (client) ID is usually the GUID generated for you by Azure. However this is not a hard requirement (but is the default when generated and what is recommended). This can be controlled in the Azure Active Directory Portal under the Application Registration Page -> Expose an API and can be changed if you wish:

[image: Application ID URI]