# Angular 16 using MSAL, the interceptor is not adding bearer token on dev server

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, microsoft-identity-platform, msal-angular

Angular 16 using MSAL 3 with following code in app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MsalModule, MsalService, MSAL_INSTANCE, MsalInterceptor, MsalGuard } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import {
  PublicClientApplication,
  InteractionType,
} from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PublicPageComponent } from './public-page/public-page.component';
import { RestrictedPageComponent } from './restricted-page/restricted-page.component';
import { AddUserComponent } from './add-user/add-user.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ListTeamsComponent } from './list-teams/list-teams.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './Pages/home-page/home-page.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './Pages/Partial/navbar/navbar.component';
import { AppLayoutModule } from './layout/app.layout.module';
import { SearchUserComponent } from './search-user/search-user.component';
import { NgxJsonViewerModule } from 'ngx-json-viewer';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PublicPageComponent,
    RestrictedPageComponent,
    AddUserComponent,
    ListTeamsComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SearchUserComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot(
      new PublicClientApplication({
        auth: {
          clientId: environment.AzureAppClientId,
          redirectUri: environment.redirectURL,
          authority:
            'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + environment.AzureTenantId,
        },
        cache: {
          cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
          storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
        },
        system: {
          allowNativeBroker: false, // Disables native brokering support
        },
      }),
      {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
        authRequest: {
          scopes: ['user.read'],
        },
      },
      {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
        protectedResourceMap: new Map([
          ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.Read']],
          [environment.ProtectedAPIServer, [environment.ProtedtedAPIScope]],
        ]),
      }
    ),
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppLayoutModule,
    NgxJsonViewerModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    MsalService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    MsalGuard,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My environment file for dev server is:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  redirectURL: 'https://applicationURL.com',
  smartUCCAPIURL: 'https://applicationAPI.com/',
  AzureAppClientId: '123',
  AzureTenantId: 'T123',
  ProtectedAPIServer: 'https://applicationURL.com',
  ProtedtedAPIScope: 'api://abc/api.scope',
};
```

app.component.ts

```
//https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js
import { AuthenticationResult } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { Message } from 'primeng/api';
import {
  faBook,
  faUser,
  faContactBook,
  faSearch,
  faTrowel,
  faHamburger,
  faAmbulance,
  faAnchorCircleCheck,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LayoutService } from 'src/app/layout/service/app.layout.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'test';
  searchIcon = faSearch;
  faHamburger = faHamburger;
  userIcon = faUser;
  userName = '';
  message: Message[] = [];
  showLeftNav: boolean = true;
  isAuthorized: boolean = true;
  showAndHideLeftNav() {
    this.showLeftNav = !this.showLeftNav;
  }

  constructor(
    private authService: MsalService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    public layoutService: LayoutService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.instance.initialize();
    this.authService.instance.handleRedirectPromise().then((res) => {
      if (res != null && res.account != null) {
        this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(res.account);
      }
    });
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    //console.log(this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount());
    return this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount() != null;
  }

  IsAuthorized() {
    return this.isAuthorized;
  }

  showLogin() {
    this.isAuthorized = true;
  }
  login() {
    // this.authService.loginRedirect();

    this.authService
      .loginPopup()
      .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
        console.log(response);

        const header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });

        this.http
          .get(
            environment.apiURL+
              'api/User/IsUserAuthorized?userAZID=' +
              response.account.localAccountId
          )
          .subscribe((resp) => {
            if (resp) {
              sessionStorage.setItem(
                'loggedUserID',
                response.account.localAccountId
              );
              
              this.userName = response.account.username;
              this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
              this.isAuthorized = true;
            }else{
              this.isAuthorized = false;
            }
          });
      });
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logoutPopup({
      mainWindowRedirectUri: '/',
    });
  }
}
```

The app will pass the token to .NET core web api on .NET 7, code:

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

controller file

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:scopes")]
[Authorize]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
  //controller actions
}
```

appSettings.json

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "scopes": "api.scope",
    "ClientId": "1238cb2b-036e-4d68-8527-fadee8f8d09d",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "TenantId": "cf67f1e5-599e-49fa-9afb-b306b580e922"
  },
```

All works good on local machine, but not on development server. Any idea why? I can see that the call to the web api just not including the bearer token on dev server (it adds on local).

Could the issue is with the MsalInterceptor?

I tried changing values of environment file in angular project to have different values for "ProtectedAPIServer" to be either localhost or the server address like myAPIServer.com.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66543702/msal-angular-http-interceptor-for-localhost-not-attaching-token